# Understanding chained .map and .filter with .dispatch and arrow functions in React server-side rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

I am coming from a straightforward Express background and learning how to do server-side rendering with React.

I came across an example app, that had it's route defined as follows:

```
export default [
    {
        path: "/",
        component: Home,
        exact: true,
    },
...
}
```

The server handles the routes like this:

```
app.get( "/*", ( req, res ) => {
...
 const dataRequirements =
        routes
            .filter( route => matchPath( req.url, route ) ) // filter matching paths
            .map( route => route.component ) // map to components
            .filter( comp => comp.serverFetch ) // check if components have data requirement
            .map( comp => store.dispatch( comp.serverFetch( ) ) ); // dispatch data requirement

    Promise.all( dataRequirements ).then( ( ) => {
        const jsx = (
                 <ReduxProvider store={ store }>
                     <StaticRouter context={ context } location={ req.url }>
```

I understand the modularity of the routes, and the general process of how this string of methods is achieving any required data. From what I understand:

1. the routes objects are pulled via filter
2. the necessary routes to be funneled into the LinkRouter are mapped to their required component

This is where I get hazy, as I don't understand what calling .filter().map()**.filter().map()** actually does to a datatype, I've never seen that layering of method calls and cannot find a resource explaining it.

I understand then that Promise.all calls all the data, then waits and calls the arrow function with no arguments. But I'm having trouble on the 3rd and 4th calls to filter and map, and how Promise.all( dataRequirements ) works to call and await all necessary data calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just modifying the array further with the second `filter` and `map` - you `filter` out unsuitable elements, you `map` those into a format that your next `filter` call will use, and finally you `map` those into a format for your `Promise.all` call.

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is a `Promise` method that, when given an iterable collection, resolves only when all resolvable elements in the collection have resolved. It essentially waits until all promises in the collection have been resolved individually, `then` executes a success function.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense! I never rationalized map as returning a new collection to filter and map again, but that actually makes total sense. I've only ever used map as a in-place modification strategy.

Am I right in thinking this means that each component **must** have a ```serverFetch()``` method to dispatch defined, even if it does nothing? Therefore the ```Promise.all()``` will call all of them and ASAP simply move on to handling the request?

Comment: No, the `Promise.all` will only call items with a Promise (so if an item does not have a promise, it will be ignored).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a ton for all the help!

Comment: No problem whatsoever, always glad to help @antonig.